# Last item of FlatList trimmed from bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling, react-native-flatlist

I am displaying a FlatList with variable number of items and the last item always is not visible completely (border bottom).

[image]

**render()**

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList style={styles.list} containContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 20}}
          ...
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**CSS**

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
list: {
   flex: 1,
   width: "95%"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong style property for the flat list, it is contentContainerStyle not containContainerStyle. You will have to increase it according to the size of your item.

```
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20}} />
```